# NSMutableArray objectatindex always shows the last Object

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray, multiple-views

my problem is that my `NSMutableArray` always get the last element with the `objectatindex`-method.

I have an array with some classes derived from `UIViewController`. I want to show one View after another.

first i fill the array:

```
ContactViewController *ContactView = [[ContactViewController alloc]init];
QuestionViewController *QuesView = [[QuestionViewController alloc]init];;
ContactView.mydelegate = self;
[QuesView setDelegate:self];


[Views addObject:ContactView];

Views =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:11];
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    [QuesView setParam:@"text" :i ];
    [Views addObject:QuesView];
}
```

after that i want to get the actual view and jump to the next like that:

```
-(IBAction)Button:(id)sender
{

    UIViewController *newView = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    newView =  (UIViewController*)[Views objectAtIndex:enumerator];
    [self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion: nil];
    enumerator++;
     //dismiss old view here....

    NSLog(@"number %d",[newView getNumber]);
}
```

the new view is not shown and the number in the log is always the last number of the array. I tried to go with a for loop through all element in "Views" but there is always the last number in every object....

any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to create multiple QuestionViewController instances. But you actually create only one object and call setParam on it 11 times.

Also this line `[Views addObject:ContactView]` has no effect, because you create a new array object and assign it to Views in the next line. The same thing with `UIViewController *newView = [[UIViewController alloc]init]`. Hope you are using ARC, otherwise this would create a memory leak!